# Why am I not able to have multiple domain names together with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have to sub domains I want to redirect to one nginx server: first.domainOne.com and second.domainTwo.net

I have two files in my nginx sites-available directory (each file has a symlink that points to it in sites-enable):
first.server file content:

```
server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name first.domainOne.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

second.server file content:

```
server{ 
        server_name second.domainTwo.net;

        root /usr/share/nginx/test;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {                                                                                                                    
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }                                                                                                                                      
    }
```

When I enable both files, I am only able to access to the content of /usr/share/nginx/www (if I go to first.domainOne.com or second.domainTwo.net).

The only way I have to be able to display my second server's content (/usr/share/nginx/test) is to disable (remove) the first.server file from sites-enable.

Here is my nginx.conf :

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
    }

    http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

EDIT: Both redirections points directly to the server name (ie http://server.name) but the debug log shows it detects the two different URL used):

```
http://first.domainOne.com -> http://server.name
http://second.domainTwo.net -> http://server.name
```

server.name is the server on which my nginx instance is hosted.

What do I miss ? Are my configuration files incorrect or do I need to activate an option in nginx.conf ?

Comment: Are you testing on your local machine?

Comment: No, on a remote server

Comment: try explicitly including both the `sites-enabled` files, ie
`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/first.server;`
`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/second.server;`
and see if the order matters

Comment: Order matters. If I revert first and second, the second (which is set first in nginx.conf) will always display (whatever the URL). I also underline that both are subdomain redirections. I don't know it it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx supports multiple server blocks, and your syntax looks reasonable. I suspect the problem may be with something that is not seen above. Try to keep slimming down search server block and see if you can find the problem that way. You can also try removing other files from /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf to continue the simplify the problem.

Following [General debugging tips for Nginx](http://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/nginx/debugging/) may also solve your problem.

You might also try starting from [simple Nginx server block examples](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample) and then building them to match your needs.

Finally, your prose mentioned that there was redirection involved, but I don't see redirection  in the code your pasting. Is part of your configuration missing from what you posted? The problem could be in there.

Comment: Redirection is made from external servers, I added some info about it. It is a simple web redirection.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Examining debug logs showed me that the /test/ addresses did not point to /usr/share/nginx/test but to /usr/share/nginx/test/test. This made the correct redirection fail.